# Запятая между частями ССП, являющегося частью БСП

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, сложное-предложение, ссп, бсп

*Зарисовки работают лучше, чем словесное конспектирование: вы получаете более наглядное представление изучаемого[,] и информация легче усваивается.*

Я правильно понимаю, что при наличии общей поясняемой двумя частями ССП третьей части, предшествующей им и связанной с ними бессоюзной связью, запятая между частями ССП **не ставится** вне зависимости того, какой характер отношений между ними — однородный, перечислительный или неоднородный, условно‑следственный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение о постановке запятой может зависеть **от структуры предложения.**

(1) **Зарисовки работают лучше, чем словесное конспектирование: вы получаете более наглядное представление изучаемого и информация легче усваивается.**

Здесь два предложения составляют общее следствие и читаются в одну фразу. Поэтому запятая перед И не ставится.

Но попробуем **изменить предложение:**

(2) Зарисовки работают лучше, чем словесное конспектирование: вы получаете более наглядное представление изучаемого, **и в этом случае** информация легче усваивается.

Второе предложение получает **собственный распространитель** в виде наречного сочетания, и тогда тесная связь предложений нарушается.

Теперь уже это предложение не входит в разъянительную часть,
 и запятая ставится.

Comment: 1) Можно сказать, что их общая связь с первой частью БСП имеет бОльшую синтаксическую и семантическую значимость, чем их связь друг с другом, поэтому и имеет бОльший вес в определении пунктуации?

Comment: 2) Собственный распространитель категорически разрывает связь с первой, разъясняемой частью БСП, даже если тот факт, что информация легче усваивается, по смыслу вполне может быть примером эффективности зарисовок?

Comment: Между предложениями (2) и (3) существует причинно-следственная связь.  Мы можем их объединить, при этом они совместно будут обозначать причину того, почему зарисовки работают лучше. В то же время можно считать, что только предложение (2) непосредственно является причиной того, что они работают лучше, а предложение (3) можно считать самостоятельной частью со значением следствия.  Таким образом, автор имеет некоторую свободу действий, однако обозначить свой выбор он может через структуру сложного предложения, разрывая связь (2) и (3) с помощью распространителя (или другим способом).

Comment: Таки образом, исходя из семантики, мы выбираем нужную грамматику и структуру предложения, а знаки препинания должны соответствовать правилам, отнесенным к этой грамматике.

Answer (score 2):

Начну с примеров:

***Было у Анны необъяснимое ощущение: еще чуть-чуть и вся эта история кончится(Щерб.); Останавливаться было нельзя: ноги засасывало и следы наливались водой (Пауст.)***

Запятая перед И в ССП не ставится, так как есть общая для этих простых предложений часть, к которой ССП присоединяется бессоюзной связью.

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=132#pp132) Общей может быть поясняемая двумя частями сложносочиненного предложениия третья часть, предшествующая им и связанная с ними бессоюзной связью: *Берегов не видать: их скрыла ночь и оттолкнули куда-то широкие волны разлива (М. Г.); Он чувствовал себя нехорошо: тело было слабо и в глазах ощущалась тупая боль (Купр.); Одно было ясно: ссора оказалась окончательной и назад он не вернётся; Это похоже на то, что мы наблюдаем в кожных покровах: при каждом нашем движении одежда стирает мёртвые клетки поверхностного слоя и их заменяют нижележащие клетки*.

***Но: Через час явилась возможность ехать: метель утихла, небо прояснилось, и мы отправились (П.) — последняя часть не входит в разъяснение.***